# How to configure Spartacus with custom storefront?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

Can anyone let me know, what the are the steps to follow when we integrate spartacus with custom storefront.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77838084/cx-media-cx-carousel-not-emitting-data

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I fully understand the question. Are you talking about base sites?

If so the documentation for how to do it can be found here https://sap.github.io/cloud-commerce-spartacus-storefront-docs/context-configuration/.

Hope this helps

Comment: Currently we are using yb2cacceleratorstorefront for base site. If i want to use custom storefront what are the changes need to be done in spartacus code and spartacussampledataaddon.